# C# Windows Form help! A panel is not displaying

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have to do a chessboard in C# windows form with panels. I have a button, two textboxs (to set the number of columns and rows) and one big panel where I will place the small panles.

This is the Button Click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x, y, width, height, colors=0;
            Panel paneln;

            rows = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            columns = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            height = panel1.Size.Height / rows;
            width = panel1.Size.Width / columns;
            x = panel1.Location.X;
            y = panel1.Location.Y;

            for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            {
                for(int k = 0;k<columns;k++)
                {
                    paneln = new Panel();
                    paneln.Location = new Point(x, y);
                    paneln.Size = new Size(width, height);

                    if (colors % 2 == 0)
                        paneln.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    else
                        paneln.BackColor = Color.White;
                   
                    paneln.BringToFront();
                    panel1.SendToBack();
                    this.Controls.Add(paneln);

                    x += width;
                    colors++;
                }
                x= panel1.Location.X;
                y += height;
                if (columns % 2 == 0) colors++;
            }
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

It works fine but if the columns value is even, the last panel (the bottom right one) is not displayed.

For example with rows=4 and columns=4 i get this:

B W B W

W B W B

B W B W

W B W

I tried to force the internal for to perform one more loop in the last row, but then it places two panels,which actually makes sense, and makes me think it actually creates the panel object but somehow it isn't shown.

Any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: You are missing : this.Controls.Add(paneln) which adds the panel to the form.

Comment: Using controls for 'drawing' is an insane overhead and is completely unnecessary. Just use the `Paint` event of the parent panel and draw the checkboard by `Graphics.FillRectangle`. Call `panel.Invalidate` whenever you need to repaint the board (eg. when a move happens).

Comment: @jdweng how am i missing the last one? the loop when i=3 and k=3 it's perfomed

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg this is the way our teacher said, it's the first Windows Form homework, i have to do it in this way :(

Comment: The panel isn't large enough.  Are you suppose to add the new panels to the form or Panel1?  You are adding the new Panels to this which I'm not sure is the Form or Panel1. The problem is the starting values of x & y.  The Location of Panel 1 should not be used to used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out!
I was doing the

```
paneln.BringToFront();
panel1.SendToBack();
```

before adding paneln to the form, so it didn't work.